# Run error: ERROR 8712 --- [ restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have **'run error'** App wrote in Spring Boot with frontend Angular JS

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-04-09 08:46:21.964 ERROR 8712 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'classPathFileSystemWatcher' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/devtools/autoconfigure/LocalDevToolsAutoConfiguration$RestartConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.devtools.classpath.ClassPathFileSystemWatcher]: Factory method 'classPathFileSystemWatcher' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Folder 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\social-network-spring-master\webapp\bower_components' must exist and must be a directory
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1134) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1028) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
at org.asaunin.socialnetwork.SocialNetworkApplication.main(SocialNetworkApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.devtools.classpath.ClassPathFileSystemWatcher]: Factory method 'classPathFileSystemWatcher' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Folder 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\social-network-spring-master\webapp\bower_components' must exist and must be a directory
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Folder 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\social-network-spring-master\webapp\bower_components' must exist and must be a directory
at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:68) ~[spring-core-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.filewatch.FileSystemWatcher.addSourceFolder(FileSystemWatcher.java:124) ~[spring-boot-devtools-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.autoconfigure.LocalDevToolsAutoConfiguration$RestartConfiguration.newFileSystemWatcher(LocalDevToolsAutoConfiguration.java:159) ~[spring-boot-devtools-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.autoconfigure.LocalDevToolsAutoConfiguration$RestartConfiguration.access$000(LocalDevToolsAutoConfiguration.java:101) ~[spring-boot-devtools-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.autoconfigure.LocalDevToolsAutoConfiguration$RestartConfiguration$1.getFileSystemWatcher(LocalDevToolsAutoConfiguration.java:142) ~[spring-boot-devtools-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.classpath.ClassPathFileSystemWatcher.<init>(ClassPathFileSystemWatcher.java:61) ~[spring-boot-devtools-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.autoconfigure.LocalDevToolsAutoConfiguration$RestartConfiguration.classPathFileSystemWatcher(LocalDevToolsAutoConfiguration.java:119) ~[spring-boot-devtools-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
... 24 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like below directory is missing in your setup and application is looking for it.

> **C:\Users\User\Desktop\social-network-spring-master\webapp\bower_components**